# A lot of smoke coming from exhaust after oil change (mixed old with new oil)

Tags: nissan, oil-change, sentra

I put new oil in my nissan earlier today (5w-30) and as I was driving I started to smell what I thought was burning oil, and I noticed behind me excessive amount of smoke while driving. I went from 3rd to to neutral just to glide and smoke went away. The smoke was kind of thick but it dissipated pretty quickly. I am nervous I might have screwed something up.

Any ideas? I smelled the exhaust, no sweet smell (hooray I guess?) but I noticed the some old oil (or liquid soot maybe?) underneath the exhaust, I checked farther up see there was any oil leaking underneath the engine, and so far I didn't see anything.

If its not burning oil, I guess it could be condensation running down the pipe when I had the front elevated and burned? I doubt it thought cause it was a lot of smoke when I was driving home (mile or so)

Car: 1991 nissan sentra GXE

Comment: Could you have accidentally spilled oil on your exhaust manifold?  When you drove away and it got hot it smoked and then you pulled over and it may have burned off?  I've done that before.

Comment: Nothing from under the hood, I mean when I drove it looked like I emit a smoke screen like from a spy movie.

Comment: If it started to smoke after you drove it's possible it could have been in your engine compartment.  As your driving the wind pulls the smoke along the underside of the car.  Were you able to locate a source?

Comment: I thought it was in my engine bay but when I let it run I popped the hood, and checked for smoke. When I let it ran later that night I looked the the exhaust pipe (shortly after seeing the oil on the street) there was residual smoke still in there.

Comment: If you let your car sit and take it for a drive does it smoke again?

Comment: I will be checking the dipstick, and if its too high im gonna assume just needs to drain some oil, but if the oil levels are ok, i will take it for a drive and see if it persist.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/33613/discussion-between-andyadd-and-ducatikiller).

Comment: What color is the smoke? Is it grey, blue or white?

Comment: @andyADD  If you are satisfied that kmarsh's response below is the correct answer you can hit the check mark next to the voting arrows on the answer.  We have a reward system and he get's points for answering correctly.    :-)   TY and Happy New Year

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Possibilities include:

- Oil spilled on exhaust during the Oil Change (as mentioned in the
  comments by DucatiKiller). This can be new oil from filling, or old
  oil from the drain and/or filter replacement.
- Overfilling with replacement oil can result in burn-off. Check the oil level, check multiple reliable sources for the correct fill amount, and check the PCV valve and hose(s).
- A loose oil cap can spew oil during operation, which will eventually
  reach the exhaust system.
- A loose oil filter will drip or spray under pressure, also the drain
  plug. Check both.
- You may have removed or disconnected one end of a hose during the
  service.
- You may have filled (over-filled) the wrong part of the vehicle with
  the replacement oil. Check all your fluids for level and
  cross-contamination.
- Least likely, your vehicle may have experienced a failure of some
  kind at about the time of the oil change service. The failure could be internal like piston rings or valve guides, or an oil containment system such as the rear main seal or the valve cover gaskets.

Comment: I keep going to your second bullet point.  Seems the most likely IMO.  Nice answer.    Come to the chat room once in awhile and say HI.   http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/340/the-pitstop

Comment: I have solved the issue, after removing excess oil, I went to drive for 30 minutes, to burn off any residue, and no more smoke, and doesn't smell like burning oil anymore.

Comment: Great news, glad you worked it out!